# jScrollPane issue within Symfony

Tags: jquery, symfony1, jquery-jscrollpane

Yesterday I tried implementing jScrollPane on a resultsSuccess.php template and wasn't able to get the vertical scrollbar to work. At first I thought it was b/c I was using jquery version 1.5.2, so I downgraded to 1.4.4 and still no luck. So then I copied and pasted the source code from the demo site and disabled layout for the action, and still no luck getting the vertical scrollbars to work correctly.

Finally, I copied and pasted the source code into project/symfony/web/test.html and viola, the scrollbars work. So this leads me to believe that there is something in the symfony stack that I am missing or not enabling correctly.

I know there is a plugin for jScrollPane for symfony, but I really try to stay away from jquery plugins as they tend to maintain their own versions of jquery, so if you have multiple plugins, chances are you have multiple versions of jquery.

Anyone run into this issue before?

-- Edit --

Sigh... I was copying source from "View Generated Source", vs "View Source" (via web dev tools firefox extension). After I pasted the non-generated source it all works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the edit, I was so used to viewing "generated source" vs regular source that I ended up editing the wrong classes. After just viewing source everything worked as expected.